# NMAP Always says host is down (when using -Pn it says ports filtered)

Tags: networking, security, port, nmap

I am running Kali 2.0 (Kali sana) and I have a problem with `NMAP`, it everytime says that host is down when I scan it (even myself with firewall off)... When I try online `nmap` (https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap) on my IP it works... I do not know what can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing this message:

```
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -PN
```

Usually, `nmap` sends a number of probes to determine if the host is actually up or down, one of them is `ping`ing the host. `ping` uses ICMP packets to reach the host, so if you're seeing that message it's either because the destination host has incoming `ICMP` packets filtered, either because *you* have outgoing ICMP packets filtered in your firewall.

As per the situation that you describe (`nmap` run from an external source works fine but *you locally* are unable to `nmap` any host), the most likely reason is that *you* have outgoing ICMP packets filtered. Note that router is not the only device capable of blocking traffic. Antivirus, software firewalls also are.

Comment: I see that but when i try online nmap tool it works.... It does that thing "host seems down" for every host i try...

Comment: Then you probably have outgoing ICMP requests filtered.

Comment: My router is not filtering ICMP packets nor there is other way it can be filtered as it works on my WIndows machine (main machine - Kali is Dual Boot)... And I do not have Antivirus or firewall on Kali.

Comment: It suddenly stopped to work even on Windows...

Comment: have the same problem here.